# Data type that accepts multiple interface type

Tags: dictionary, go, interface

I'll do my best to explain my situation here.

So, I am creating a DAL for my app. It accesses both redis and mysql.

The redis interface is as:

File NoSqlDBClient.go:

```
type NosqlDb interface {
     HGet() string
}

type NosqlClient struct {
    key string
}

func GetNosqlClient() *NosqlClient{
    return &NosqlClient{}
}

func (ns *NosqlClient) HGet()string {
//actual implemenation would be different
    return ns.key
}
```

File SqldbClient.go:

```
type SqlDB interface {
    ExecQuery()
}

type SqlClient struct {
    query string
}

func GetsqlClient() *SqlClient{
    return  &SqlClient{}
}

func (s *SqlClient) ExecQuery()string {
    //actual implemenation would be different
    return s.query
}
```

Now I need to implement a DBClient Factory which maintains a map of dbtype and client.
It goes like this

File DBClientFactory.go

```
type DBClientfactory struct {
    clientmap[string] //what data type to use???
}

func GetNoSqlDBClient() NosqlDb{
    client:=NoSqlDBClient.GetNosqlClient()
    clientmap['nosql'] = client
    return client
}

func GetSqlDBClient() SqlDB{
    client:=SqlDBClient.GetsqlClient()
    clientmap['sql'] = client
    return client
}
```

The problem is How can I hold different type of clients in one map?
I thought of defining another interface `DBFactory` that has the other two interfaces embedded in it. But that obviously doesn't work because all methods are not implemented by the individual interface.

How should I go about this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `interface{}` for the map value type, but then you lose type safety and would have to use type assertions or type switches.

Instead you should use 2 distinct map types, one for each interface you want to store:

```
type DBClientfactory struct {
    nosqldbs map[string]NosqlDb
    sqldbs   map[string]SqlDB
}
```

And each function or method would use the appropriate map, `GetNoSqlDBClient()` would use `DBClientfactory.nosqldbs`, and `GetSqlDBClient()` would use `DBClientfactory.sqldbs`.

If you only have one instance of each client, then don't use a map at all, just use simple fields:

```
type DBClientfactory struct {
    nosqldb NosqlDb
    sqldb   SqlDB
}
```

Comment: Yes, but this eliminates the use of map altogether. I would not keep a map if I keep different fields in the factory struct, which are essentially the keys of the map.

Comment: @AyushGoyal If you only have one instance per type, then don't use maps at all. Using a map here is not a good idea.

Comment: @AyushGoyal the implementation of your getters is either pointless or incomplete anyway, what's the purpose of the map if you're just overwriting its values every time, with a hardcoded key and never actually reading from it.

Comment: This was a brief example to explain the crux of the problem. The actual getters are however different and complete, in the sense , they make use of the values. The keys for the map can be of different type for a single client, so yes I may or may not have to overwrite values

Comment: @icza I think I have to go ahead with distinct map types. Although I wish I could do that with a single map in Go

Comment: @AyushGoyal you could use something like this if you want to avoid two maps: https://play.golang.com/p/in8EiFLNaJ-

Comment: @mkopriva yes that's another workaround to be considered, thanks!